# AutoMapper mapping to a property of a nullable property

Tags: c#, automapper

How can you map a property to a sub-property that may be null?

eg the following code will fail with a NullReferenceException because the Contact's User property is null.

```
using AutoMapper;

namespace AutoMapperTests
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactModel>()
                .ForMember( x => x.UserName,  opt => opt.MapFrom( y => y.User.UserName ) );

            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

            var c = new Contact();

            var co = new ContactModel();

            Mapper.Map( c, co );
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contact
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
    }

    public class ContactModel
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'd like ContactModel's UserName to default to an empty string instead.

I have tried the NullSubstitute method, but I assume that's trying to operate with User.Username, rather than just on the User property.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could write the mapping code like follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactModel>()
            .ForMember( x => x.UserName,  opt => opt.MapFrom( y => (y.User != null) ? y.User.UserName : "" ) );
```

This will check if the `User` is null or not and then assign either an emtpy string or the `UserName`.

Comment: Great minds think alike - just managed to figure out the exact same solution :-)

Comment: What about nullable DateTime? properties?

Answer (score 6):

If you find yourself doing a lot of null checking like in Dave's answer, you might consider applying the technique I've blogged about a while ago: [Getting rid of null checks in property chains](http://www.subspace.nl/blog/2010_Getting%20rid%20of%20null%20checks.pdf). This will allow you to write this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Contact, ContactModel>()
    .ForMember(x => x.UserName,
        opt => opt.NullSafeMapFrom(y => y.User.UserName) ?? string.Empty);
```

Comment: Hi 
@Sandor Drieënhuizen, is the `?? string.Empty`piece above needed? I've seen some examples in your article where you only use the `opt.NullSafeMapFrom` piece

Comment: @AdolfoPerez: the `?? string.Empty` is not necessary, it's just a convenient way to make sure the result is never `null`.

Comment: Url is now down.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I've updated the url. The blog was gone but I kept a PDF file of the post.

Comment: URL is down again

Comment: @Khoward Yeah, sadly the blog is long gone. But C# (and AutoMapper with it) has evolved a lot ever since so none of it applies anymore.

Answer (score 5):

A solution I've used is to create a closure around the original delegate, which wraps it in a try/catch block. It's unfortunately necessary to use `Expression.Compile()` to stop Visual Studio from catching the exception when it's thrown in the original delegate. Probably not recommended in high performance environments, but I've never had any issue using it in regular UI stuff. Your milage may vary.

### Extension method

```
public static class AutoMapperExtensions
{
    public static void NullSafeMapFrom<T, TResult>(this IMemberConfigurationExpression<T> opt, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> sourceMemberExpression)
    {
        var sourceMember = sourceMemberExpression.Compile();

        opt.MapFrom(src =>
        {
            try
            {
                return sourceMember(src);
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {}

            return default(TResult);
        });
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Target, opt => opt.NullSafeMapFrom(src => src.Something.That.Will.Throw));
```

Comment: The performance hit caused by the `Expression.Compile()` call can be largely mitigated by applying a caching mechanism. The try-catch is a bigger problem though, performance wise. But like you said, if only called occasionally (unlike in large loops), it shouldn't be a problem.